# PHP - isset returns true for non existing array key

Tags: php, php-5.5

I thought I knew everything about php until I bumped into this:

```
$foo = 'hello';
isset($foo['a']);     // returns false - OK
isset($foo['a']['b']; // returns false - OK
isset($foo['a'][0]);  // returns true! WTF?!
```

Could anybody explain me the result of the 4th line? Tested with php 5.5.36.

Comment: `var_dump($foo['a'][0])`

Comment: also found on http://phpfiddle.org/ with this code `$foo = 'hello';
echo isset($foo['a'])?  'yes 2' : "";      // returns false - OK
echo isset($foo['a']['b'])?  'yes 3' : "";  // returns false - OK
echo isset($foo['a'][0]) ?  'yes 4' : ""; `

Comment: but foo is string not array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the question is somewhat misleading, because `isset` returns `true` for any variable that is not `null`. Since `$foo` is a string, and not an array, `$foo["a"]` gives an *Illegal string offset* warning. PHP assumes that you meant to cast `"a"` as an integer offset and does that implicitly, turning `$foo["a"]` into `$foo[0]` which gives you the string `"h"` (*the first offset of the string*). Since the return value is another string the expression becomes `"h"[0]`, which is just `"h"` again.

So in other words, `$foo["a"][0]` where `$foo = "hello"` is the same thing as `$foo[0][0]` which gives us `"h"`.

But as far as non-existing array keys, `isset` would definitely return `false` since a non-existing key leads to a non-existing value which is implicitly `null`.